# Angular service "this" is changing context the window object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, window, this, angular-services

I am sure I have messed this up somehow, and am missing something pretty obvious. The goal is to provide a service which exposes some basic authentication (login, logout, isLoggedIn) and potentially authorization functionality.

When the page loads, I check a cookie and attempt to retrieve the user from the server if the session cookie indicates the user is logged in.  I don't anticipate many full page transitions, but I think having a 1-2 full pages is likely the best approach, and I don't want to store the user ina cookie.

I understood that a service is created by appending data / methods to the this object.  I get that inside of the promises that the this context changes, by why in the isLoggedIn method does the this context refer to the window object?

```
angular.module('myNgApplication').service('MyAuthentication', function ($cookies, UserProxy) {

    this.user = null ;

    (function(){
        var SESSION_COOKIE = 'loggedIn'
        if($cookies[SESSION_COOKIE]) {
            var self = this
            UserProxy.retrieveSession().then(function(authResponse){
                console.log('init')
                console.log(self)
                self.user = authResponse
            })
        }
    }).call(this)



    this.isLoggedIn = function() {
        console.log('isLoggedIn')
        console.log(this)
        return this.user != null ;
    }

    this.login = function (email, password) {
        var self = this
        return UserProxy.login(email, password).then(function(authResponse){
            self.user = authResponse
            return self.user
        })
    }
})
```

Usage:

```
var myWelcomeController = function($scope, MyAuthentication, $timeout) {


    $scope.$watch(function(){ return MyAuthentication.user }, function() {
        console.log(MyAuthentication.user)
        $scope.user = MyAuthentication.user ;
        $timeout(MyAuthentication.isLoggedIn, 1000)
    });

};
```

Console:

```
init 
Constructor {user: null, isLoggedIn: function, login: function}

isLoggedIn 
Window {top: Window, window: Window, location: Location, external: Object, chrome: Object…}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$timeout` is only a tiny angular wrapper around javascript [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/DOM/window.setTimeout) function and as such behaves in a similar fashion.

Consider following example:

```
var foo = {
  bar: function(){
    console.log('bar this =', this);
  }
};
foo.bar(); //-> bar this = Object {bar: function}
setTimeout(foo.bar); //-> bar this = Window {top: Window, window: Window, location: Location, external: Object, chrome: Object…}
```

When you call `foo.bar()` javascript runtime sets this context of function `bar` to `foo`. When you call `setTimeout(foo.bar)` the `setTimeout` function has a only reference to `bar` function and calls it with a this context set to `Window` - exactly as stated in [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.setTimeout#Explanation).

Finally you can make your code work with a following change:

```
$timeout(function(){
  MyAuthentication.isLoggedIn()
}, 1000);
```

Comment: it never crossed my mind it was the timeout.  I was so focused on debugging and the $timeout was a throw away test.  Thank you...